# Trouble in insertion of string in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am writing a program to insert data to linked list and print it.

**LinkedList.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
  char *data;
  struct node *next;
};

void insert(struct node** head_ref,char *new_data)
{
struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *last = *head_ref;
strcpy(new_node->data,new_data);
new_node->next = NULL;
if (*head_ref == NULL)
{
   *head_ref = new_node;//assigning head node
   return;
}

while (last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;//this helps to traverse to last node

last->next = new_node;
return;
}


void printList(struct node *node)//function to print the linked list
{
  while (node != NULL)
  {
   printf(" %s ", node->data);
   node = node->next;
  }
}


int main() {
   int t;
   char datas[1000];
   scanf("%d",&t);
   struct node* head=NULL;
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<t;i++)
   {
      scanf("%s",datas);//this data should be added into the linkedlist
      insert(&head,datas);
   }
   printList(head);

  return 0;
 }
```

This program works well for integer but if i use character string instead it showing that there is no response on stdout
I have been trying to debug the code for more hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have missed memory allocation, try this:

```
void insert(struct node** head_ref,char *new_data)
{
struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *last = *head_ref;

// you should allocate memory because you use data as char *
new_node->data = malloc(strlen(new_data)+1); 

/* you can use new_node->data = strdup(new_data);  
instead of new_node->data = malloc(strlen(new_data)); and strcpy(new_node->data,new_data); 
because strdup allocate and copy string with exact size */
strcpy(new_node->data,new_data); 

new_node->next = NULL;
if (*head_ref == NULL)
{
   *head_ref = new_node;//assigning head node
   return;
}

while (last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;//this helps to traverse to last node

last->next = new_node;
return;
}
```

Comment: that will result in undefined behavior as well. How much space does new_data takes? is it strlen(new_data) bytes?

Comment: yes, it is, new_data is read from scanf in main function, so lenght is different from 0

Comment: Let me rephrase, does the new data need strlen(new_data) bytes? Where is the null terminator stored? How much space does the string `""` take? What is its length?

Comment: no, but in this case the string is read with scanf so we have the null terminator stored

Comment: And, did you allocate space for it (null terminator) in `new_node->data`?

Comment: no because in the case of the question strlen does not return unkown value while the strings are read with scanf function, so we does not need

Comment: Assume I insert the string `a` to scanf. How much bytes to I need to allocate in `new_node->data` in order to store this string?

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives undefined behavior.

Have a look at the documentation of [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

Long story short, `strcpy()` requires the `destination` (your `new_node->data`) to be an allocated `char` array, but you have not allocated the data for it, and you are writing to an undefined (and unallocated) memory.

To overcome it, either allocate space dynamically for the new string (and don't forget to free it when a node is released), or make `data` a `char[]` instead of a `char*`.

In addition, just remember [buffer overflow weakness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Since it seems like educational purpose code, just think about it - don't try to solve it, IMO.